# Chinese citizen/passport making connection flight in Zurich

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, zurich, chinese-citizens

If I hold a Chinese passport, but I have a green card USA and I am landing in Zurich and staying at the airport for my connecting flight to Beijing, do I need a visa?

Comment: @Gagravarr Not an exact duplicate. The linked answer posses the question, "If you can stay in the international area (“transit airside”)..." and point out that in some German airports you cannot do so. Thus the above question could be rewritten as, "Can one transit international flights in Zurich airport without leaving the internationality section of the airport?"

Answer (score 2):

Chinese citizens can transit through Zurich airport without leaving the international transit area of the airport,[(1)](http://www.zurich-airport.com/passengers-and-visitors/airport-services-en/layover-and-lounges) without a visa.[(2)](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/airport-transit-visa.html)

The transit area in Zurich has reasonable facilities[(3)](http://www.zurich-airport.com/passengers-and-visitors/airport-services-en/layover-and-lounges) including a transit hotel[(4)](http://www.zurich-airport.com/the-company/media/news-center/2014/jun/zrh-2014-06-25-transit) should you be making a long transit or overnight transit.

Comment: Care to add a few references?

Comment: The last paragraph and the websites it's based on are incorrect: Holding a green card does not afford any right to enter Switzerland or the rest of the Schengen area without a visa if you aren't already allowed to do it based on your citizenship.

Comment: @Relaxed There are a large number of websites that state the same as I wrote. Your assertion is based on what?

Comment: @Rincewind42 The Schengen [Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20131018) and [Borders Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02006R0562-20131126). Note in particular that article 3 of the Visa Code mentions the Green Card rule *for airport transit* but that there is nothing like that anywhere else, and in particular nothing in article 5 of the Borders Code (which is the legal basis for the obligation to hold a visa to enter).

Comment: I also invite you to check the websites of a few consulates or foreign ministries from EU countries. Their quality varies but I would be surprised if any of them mention something like this. I think it's simply the result of a confusion between the rules that apply for airport transit and the regular entry rules as the difference is easy to overlook.